# Why Hibernate Validator doesn't care @Valid but @NotNull only?

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to check constraints look like this.

```java
class Registration {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private User user;
}

class User {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Max(128)
    @Min(0)
    @PositiveOrZero
    private int age;
}
```

When I try to invoke `isValidFor(Registration.class, "user", null)` it populates a non empty `Set<ConstraintViolation<Registration>>` as expected.

But it returns an empty set for `isValidFor(Registration.class, "user", <invalid User>)`.

```java
        final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        final User user = User.newInstanceWithInvalidAge();
        Assertions.assertThat(validator.validate(user))
                .isNotEmpty(); // succeeds
        final BeanDescriptor constraints = validator.getConstraintsForClass(Registration.class);
        for (final PropertyDescriptor constrainedProperty
                : constraints.getConstrainedProperties()) {
            log.debug("constrained property: {}", constrainedProperty);
            for (final ConstraintDescriptor<?> constraintDescriptor
                    : constrainedProperty.getConstraintDescriptors()) {
                log.debug("\tconstraint descriptor: {}", constraintDescriptor);
            }
        }
        final Registration registration = Registration.builder().user(user).build();
        Assertions.assertThat(validator.validate(registration))
                .isNotEmpty(); // succeeds
        Assertions.assertThat(validator.validateValue(Registration.class, "user", user))
                .isNotEmpty(); // fails
```

Here comes what it prints.

```
constrained property: PropertyDescriptorImpl{
    propertyName=user,
    cascaded=true
}
constraint descriptor: ConstraintDescriptorImpl{
    annotation=j.v.c.NotNull,
    payloads=[],
    hasComposingConstraints=true,
    isReportAsSingleInvalidConstraint=false,
    elementType=FIELD,
    definedOn=DEFINED_LOCALLY,
    groups=[interface javax.validation.groups.Default],
    attributes={groups=[Ljava.lang.Class;@664a9613,
                message={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message},
                payload=[Ljava.lang.Class;@5118388b},
                constraintType=GENERIC,
                valueUnwrapping=DEFAULT
    }
```

Why the `isValidFor` method doesn't care for `@Valid`?

I'm working on following dependencies.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1-b12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.23.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the `@Valid` is not honored by the `validateProperty` method.

> `<T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateProperty(T object, String propertyName, Class<?>... groups)` validates a given field or property of an object. An `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when `validateProperty()` is called and `object` is null or `propertyName` is null, empty or invalid or null is passed to the varargs `groups` parameter. The property name is the JavaBeans property name (as defined by the JavaBeans `Introspector` class). This method implements the logic described in Validation routine but only to the given property. ***`@Valid` is not honored by this method.*** This method is useful for partial object validation.

I still want to know why.